# Why did the Occupant have photos of the prison fallout shelter?

Tags: the-lost-room

In [*The Lost Room*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Room), all the Objects are things that actually belonged to The Occupant and happened to be with him (e.g. the Eye indeed foretells he's missing an eye; the Bus Ticket has his correct original travel route).

But one of the objects is the Photographs, a set of photos depicting the inside of a prison, down to its underground fallout shelter.

> These scenes serve as a map (and a keystone) to the Collectors vault. Granted, the Collectors could certainly have located their vault *based on* the location already provided in the pictures. But that still leaves the question:

Why would the Occupant possibly have had such pictures in his possession to begin with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy; he didn't. From among the batch of photos, only one of them - the undeveloped Polariod - was an Object. The other photos had their own significance - they were clues to the object repository; a way in. But they weren't Objects.

The only photo [objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objects_from_The_Lost_Room) were the Wedding picture and the undeveloped Polaroid.

The photos came from Barbara Stritzke's nephew, Harold (the guy with the Comb.)  He didn't know their significance, nor that the undeveloped picture was an Object.  His aunt was a member of the collectors, and the pictures formed a way for someone to access the vault despite having never been there; he was supposed to hold them until the time came, although when and what that would be was never specified.

Joe tests the undeveloped Polaroid, and confirms that it **is** an object, but never tests the rest, which is good, as he might have destroyed them.  Possibly the Polaroid object was deliberately hidden with them as a form of misdirection; a picture object hidden with regular (although significant) pictures.

Comment: 37 minutes into 'The Comb,' Miller gets the bundle of photos from Harold, and tests one of them, confirming it's an object. You're saying it's just that one photo, not the others? That makes sense; I definitely missed that (the one photo is undeveloped, but all of them are pretty weird). Also supported by the conclusion of 'The Box', where Miller has to _look through_ all the photos to find the one with the "Gallup" note - that's the undeveloped one. When he finds it, you don't have time to see the contents of the photo (or lack thereof) - part of why I assumed it was the whole set.

Comment: Yep; the undeveloped one is the Polaroid, which lets you see into the room before the event.  Good place to hide a photo object, though; with other photos.